# How to remove parent element in case child elements are removed from DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Script
$scope.**removableElement**=['NAME','TITLE'];

```
<div>
  <h5>Name</h5>
  <div><input type="text" ng-if="removableElement.indexOf('NAME')!=-1"/></div>
  <div><input type="text" ng-if="removableElement.indexOf('TITLE')!=-1"/></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Adress</h5>
  <div><input type="text" ng-if="removableElement.indexOf('STATE')!=-1"/></div>
  <div><input type="text" ng-if="removableElement.indexOf('CITY')!=-1"/></div>
</div>
```

Since, **removableElement** array does not contain "**STATE**" AND "**CITY**", '**div**' containing these element should be removed. Please suggest.

Comment: you should use `ng-hide` i guesss

Comment: Use [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) -- The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations. Or more informally (!a  && !b) == !(a || b)

Answer (score 0):

First do the checking. Figure out the relationships, parent to child strong, but child to parent is a weak relationship.

```js
Option 1 (much slower):

var myNode = document.getElementById("foo");
myNode.innerHTML = '';
Option 2 (much faster):

var myNode = document.getElementById("foo");
while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}
```